# What could be a select query to search records By "Last Week", "Last Month" and "Last Year"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, select

I have system in which I need to display the list of records such we are available with three options

1. Last Week
2. Last Month
3. Last Year

My table structure has a field call `createdate` which is `BIGINT` type and saves the data obtained from PHP's `time()` function.

Please guide me to get the select query to search records By "Last Week", "Last Month" and "Last Year"

Thanks

Comment: Define "Last Week", etc. Starting with Monday? Or last 7 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE createdate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 week) AND NOW();    
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE createdate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month) AND NOW() ;   
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE createdate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 year) AND NOW();
```

Comment: @OMTheEternity [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: @OMTheEternity: you should use `FROM_UNIXTIME` on your date column, not in place of `NOW()` I think...

Answer (score 2):

Many of the given queries suffer from bad usability of indexes. If your `createdate` is in unix time, the comparison should happen as well in unix time.

```
SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE createdate
        BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

should provide a way to use a range on the index over `createdate` and doesn't require a full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdate)) = YEAR(NOW())-1
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdate)) = WEEK(NOW())-1 AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdate)) = YEAR(NOW())
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdate)) = MONTH(NOW())-1 AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(createdate)) = YEAR(NOW())
```

See the [week function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) for options like first day of week.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date_col) BETWEEN
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()

SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date_col) BETWEEN
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW()


SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date_col) BETWEEN
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND NOW()
```